# Show that if $ n>1 $ then $ 3^{2^{n}} = 1 + q_{n}2^{n+2} $ for some odd integer $q_{n} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So basically we have to show that:

$ 3^{2^{n}} \equiv 1 $ mod $ (q_{n}2^{n+2}) $ for some odd integer $q_{n}$

Using Eulers theorem we can rewrite this question as:

Show $ \varphi (q_{n}2^{n+2}) = 2^{n} $ for some odd integer $ q_{n} $

So I replace $ q_{n} $ with $ (2k-1)$ for some $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $

I've gone down this route and haven't figured it out. Any ideas? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Rewriting would mean that the two questions are equivalent.  Euler's theorem is not an if-and-only-if, so you could say that "it is enough to show that" but not "we can rewrite this question as".  In fact, it is not at all true that $\phi(q_n 2^{n+2}) = 2^n$ for any integer $q_n$: Euler's theorem isn't strong enough to prove this claim, so you need to try a different route.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$3^{2^{n+1}}-1=3^{2^n2}-1=(3^{2^n})^2-1\\=(3^{2^n}-1)(3^{2^n}+1)$$

Comment: At each stage, you multiply by a number with a single factor of $2$.